# javascript onblur function for each item within a loop

Tags: javascript, java, validation, jsp

[image]

I have insert some items within a column in database, but how can i perform onblur function for validation for these item within a loop ??For instance, validation for `NAME` if empty then prompt alert, if `NRIC` length is less than certain length then prompt alert msg. How can i perform?

```
  <script>
  function fnfunction(??)
  {
    //no idea how to do validation for each item
  } 
  </script>
  <%
   String SQL   = "SELECT * FROM TB_BS_WITH UR";
   String  VALUE1 = "";
   String ROW_NO = "";
   String COL_NO = "";
    DB_Contact.makeConnection();
    DB_Contact.executeQuery(SQL);   
    while(DB_Contact.getNextQuery())
    {
        VALUE1 = DB_Contact.getColumnString("VALUE1");
        ROW_NO = DB_Contact.getColumnString("ROW_NO");
        COL_NO = DB_Contact.getColumnString("COL_NO");
    %>
   <table>
        <tr>
            <%StringTokenizer st1=n ew StringTokenizer(VALUE1, "^"); while(st1.hasMoreTokens()){%>
                <th class="fontSection">
                    <%=st1.nextToken() %>
                </th>
                <%}%>
        </tr>
        <%for(int i=0;i<Integer.parseInt(ROW_NO);i++){ %>
            <tr>
                <%for(int j=0;j<Integer.parseInt(COL_NO);j++){ %>
                    <td>
                        <input type="text"name="<%=j%>_NAME_<%=i %>" id="<%=j%>_NAME_<%=i %>" onblur="fnfunction(???)">
                    </td>
                    <%}%>
            </tr>
            <%}%>
    </table>
    <%
      } DB_Contact.takeDown();
    %>
```

current output... how to validate for each column ?
   [image]

Comment: were you able to come up with a solution, either answer help?

Answer (score 0):

To validate on `blur`, you could do something like this.
Don't assign the event inline within the `input` tag, assign after the page is loaded.

```
  window.addEventListener('load', initPage, false);

  // add blur event to all inputs
  function initPage(event) {
    var inputs = document.getElementsByTagName('INPUT');
    for (var i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++) {
      // only check text fields
      if (e.target.type === 'text') {
        inputs[i].addEventListener('blur', validateForm, false);
      }
    }
  }

  // check value of blurred element
  function validateForm(e) {
    e = e || window.event;
    e.target = e.target || e.srcElement;

    // assuming id will always be --> #_FieldName_#
    var fieldName = e.target.id.split('_')[1];

    switch (fieldName) {
      case 'Name':
        if (e.target.value === '') {
          alert(fieldName + ' cannot be blank!');
          e.target.focus();
        }
        break;

      case 'NRIC':
        if (Number(e.target.value) < 10) {
          alert(fieldName + ' cannot be less than 10!');
          e.target.focus();
        }
        break;
    }
  }
```

Comment: hmm ..regarding the fieldName .. is not the name of title .. it is an input tag.. i cant use switch case for it ..the name will be 0_Name_0, 1_Name_0, 2_Name_0,3_Name_0

Comment: that's why I `split` on _ to get the middle portion of the `id`

Answer (score 0):

You can do like bellow (one of the way) :--

In jsp :-

```
<input type="text"name="<%=j%>_NAME_<%=i %>" id="<%=j%>_NAME_<%=i %>" onblur="validateInput("+<%=j%>+",this)">
```

take look at : `onblur="validateInput("+<%=j%>+",this)"`,  `this` is the current input element

in javascript :

```
 function validateInput(cellNo,currentInput){

    if(cellNo === 0){
       // get the value from currentInputand validate as per your requirement..
    }else if(cellNo == 1){
     // get the value from currentInputand and validate as per your requirement..
    }
     .
     .
     .
}
```

Comment: hmm .. can't work for my case..
because the item position is not fixed.. example first table might be NAME^NRIC / FIN^DOB^OCCUPATION and second table might be NAME^NRIC / FIN^OCCUPATION

Comment: if i use cellNo == 3 to validate for dob when it's come to occupation will have error ..